# How to rotate the screen in ArcGIS-Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, printing, vector-grid, alignment

I need to print out my map in ArcGISOnline, however I'm using a grid system and need to rotate the screen so that I can print each map individually and have them line up. 
Any thoughts on how to do this?
I will attach a screenshot to help better understand what I mean.
[image]